# Angular directive DOM manipulation dependent on scope variables

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have read that DOM manipulation in angular should be done in the compile function of a directive, and not in the pre-link/post-link/controller. The compile function does not have access to the scope.

My problem is that I want to do DOM manipulation that is dependent on scope variables. For example, I have a list that I am passing into the directive. Within the directive, I am creating a custom select with the list items within it. Where is the right place to manipulate the DOM in this case?

Note that I am not using ng-repeat - I have found it very slow when the list becomes large.

Comment: You've misunderstood whatever you read.  DOM manipulation should be done in the directive template, and secondarily in the directive's link function (which does have access to the scope). (Note that direct, jQuery-style DOM edits are a bad idea; ideally the link function should modify model data only, and the DOM changes as a side effect.) For most purposes you don't need to touch `$compile` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you have read "DOM manipulation in angular should be done in the compile function of a directive". That contradicts the advice of the AngularJS team.

> ### Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM
>
> Directives that want to modify the DOM typically use the `link` option to register DOM listeners as well as update the DOM.
>
> -- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directives - DOM Manipulation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom)

The built-in directives, `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`, `ng-when`, etc. all do their DOM manipulation in the `link` function.

> ### compile
>
> The compile function deals with transforming the template DOM. Since most directives do not do template transformation, it is not used often.
>
> -- [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference -- compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile-)

Comment: Maybe I have it wrong, but here is the link I was reading - https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/angular-js-demystifying-directives (scroll down to the table). Maybe I need to re-phrase this to "DOM Manipulation by adding HTML elements should be done in the compile function of a directive"

Comment: The article you quote has some good material but some of the things he says are just plain wrong. The statement that no addition of directives in the post-link is allowed is completely false. Directives can be added in the postlink function but need to be compiled and linked to a scope with the `$compile` service to work properly. I would advise sticking with the advice of the AngularJS team.

Comment: That article (which I agree with @georgeawg is at best misleading, and which seems rather out of date) says: "The post-link function is the function most commonly implemented in custom AngularJS directives. In this function, almost anything reasonable can be done. The DOM can be manipulated (for itself and child elements only)..."

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. The reason this came about was due to a problem I am having (I will try to add some example code later). Basically, I had a directive where I was creating a required HTML select within the link function - the options were dependent on scope variables. I used the compile service to append it to the template. The select validated and behaved fine, but would not trigger the validation ngmessage that was sitting outside of the directive. But was the process I used correct - i.e. build it in the link and use the compile service?

Comment: Yes, the process is correct. Build it in the link function and use the `$compile` service. Check the question: [Removing directive attribute does not remove listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943023/removing-directive-attribute-does-not-remove-listener/34949607#34949607). In my answer, I remove an `ng-click` directive from the DOM. I do it in the link function, using the `$compile` service.